# Creating Kernel Thread using kernel_thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I am trying to create a kernel thread using Kernel_thread() as part of an assignment for school. I am coding based on the professors example that I believe is outdated. I am getting errors and I have no idea how to proceed.

What I am doing:

```
mypid = kernel_thread(myFirstFunctionOne, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND);
```

where myFirstFunctionOne is defined as:

```
static int myFirstFunctionOne(void *unused){
struct task_struct *tsk = current;

spin_lock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
flush_signal_handlers(current, 1);
spin_unlock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);

strcpy(tsk->comm, "My name: m_k_t_do_something_1");
set_task_state(tsk, TASK_RUNNING);
printk(KERN_NOTICE "My name: m_k_t_do_something_1 is about to be scheduled.\n");
schedule();
printk(KERN_NOTICE "My name: m_k_t_do_something_1 is now scheduled.\n");
return 0;
}
```

I am calling a function that just creates has that 1 line of code towards the end of Kernel_init, create_my_first_processes().

```
static int __ref kernel_init(void *unused)
{
int ret;

kernel_init_freeable();
/* need to finish all async __init code before freeing the memory */
async_synchronize_full();
free_initmem();
mark_readonly();
system_state = SYSTEM_RUNNING;
numa_default_policy();

flush_delayed_fput();

rcu_end_inkernel_boot();

create_my_first_processes();

if (ramdisk_execute_command) {
    ret = run_init_process(ramdisk_execute_command);
    if (!ret)
        return 0;
    pr_err("Failed to execute %s (error %d)\n",
           ramdisk_execute_command, ret);
}
...
```

This is the error I get when booting:

[Kernel Panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxmHh.jpg)

Additional info: Running ubuntu on kernel 4.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed of course... you should probably use the kthread_run() api instead ofkernel_thread() ..

Pl see this sample code:
https://github.com/slavaim/Linux-kernel-modules/blob/master/kthread/kthread.c

Also note the ref and de-ref of the task structure and cleanup in the _exit() code path.